# CREATE TRIGGER for :two tables USER & FILE. Wen user uploads file,the USER_ID column present in USER table must be generated in the other table FILE

Tags: sql-server-2008

two tables have the following columns:-

USER
user_id, password,user_name

FILE
file_id,file_name,user_id

how to create trigger which will display the user_id in FILE table when any user uploads a file.

```
create table FILE 
(
file_id int identity(1,1),
file_name varchar(30),
user_id int
)

create table USER
(
user_id int identity(1,1),
user_name nvarchar(30),
specialization nvarchar(20),
date_of_upload datetime )


     create trigger T1
     ON dbo.USER
     AFTER UPDATE OF user_id ON USER
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN  //condition
     BEGIN
     INSERT INTO FILE (USER_ID)
     SELECT USER_ID FROM USER 
     END
```

Comment: What you tried something yourself? Please post your code. If you haven't tried anything yet - go study [MSDN docs on how to create a trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) or a [MSDN Magazine article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx)

Comment: jus edited . but i'm trying to modify the trigger. if u could help

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- SQL Server doesn't have `FOR EACH ROW` feature - if you update 10 rows in a single statement, the trigger is called *once* with 10 rows in the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables
- you cannot define a column criteria on the trigger - the trigger is called whenever something in the table is updated

Try this code instead:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER T1
 ON dbo.USER
 AFTER UPDATE 
 AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.FILE(USER_ID)
        SELECT i.USER_ID 
        FROM Inserted i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.USER WHERE USER_ID = i.USER_ID)
 END
```

This will insert all `USER_ID` values that aren't already in the `dbo.USER` table